# AngularJS ng repeat performance

Tags: angularjs, performance, loops, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a ng-repeat on my html view. The array it's repeating is populated each time a user selects a checkbox. It works like a filter way.

However, I am having issues with performance. It seems to create the DOM elements again and thus doing this there is a 1-1.5 second 'freeze' delay before the results are populated on the user interface again.

The array it's repeating isnt that big - probably around 50-60 entries. Each entry in the array has two objects which do have a lot of properties. Will this affect the performance? From what I've read it seems to be because it's creating the DOM elements again.

I have tried using track by $index, which speeds it up drastically but this causes problems on the div boxes I'm displaying. Text is on the wrong results, gets mixed up etc. I have also tried using track by ($index + item). No luck - same problem. I've also tried using track by item.id - but this has the same effect of not using track by - slow.

Is there anything I can do to optimize this? Or do I just bite the bullet?

Here is my code below:

```
 <div ng-if="$ctrl.hasDataProcessed() && $ctrl.resultsAvailable()">
    <div class="acca-builder-content">
        <div class="acca-builder-header" style="border: 1px solid #1393ED;">{{"RESULTS" | translate}} ({{$ctrl.accaBuilderResultsCount}})</div>
            <ul class="tips-list-group-matches">
                <li ng-repeat="result in $ctrl.accaBuilderResults | orderBy: $ctrl.getSort" ng-class="{'match-has-link': $ctrl.canViewMatch(result.match)}" class="tip-list-group-match">
                    <tf-competition-header ng-if="result.match.CompMasterID" competition="result.match"></tf-competition-header>
                    <match-header match="result.match" tracking-screen="Tips"></match-header>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And within the controller:

```
 var buildAccaResultsFromFilter = function () {
            var results = [];
            var tips = ctrl.tips;
            for (var i = 0; i < tips.length; i++) {
                var tip = tips[i];
                if(valueInFilter("COMPETITIONS", tip.match.CompID) &&
                   valueInFilter("DATES", tip.match.MatchDateConverted) &&
                   valueInFilter("SHOW", tip.tip.TipType)) {
                    results.push(tip);
                }
            }
            if(results.length > 0) {
                ctrl.accaBuilderResults = results;
                ctrl.accaBuilderResultsCount = results.length;
                ctrl.resultsFound = true;             
            } else {
                clearAccaBuilderResults();
                ctrl.resultsFound = false;
            }
        };

        // Function called when a checkbox is clicked
        ctrl.onCheckboxChange = function (option, item) {
            item.checkState = !item.checkState;
            if(item.checkState) {
                addToFilter(option.optionKey, item.textKey);
            }
            else {
                removeFromFilter(option.optionKey, item.textKey);
            }

            if(option.onChange) {
                option.onChange(item.checkState, item.checkId);
            }

            if(ctrl.canBuildAccaResults()) {
                buildAccaResultsFromFilter();
            } else {
                clearAccaBuilderResults();
            }
        };

        // Checks if a value is present within the filter by it's key
        var valueInFilter = function (filterKey, value) {
            return ctrl.filter[filterKey].includes(value);
        };

        ctrl.resultsAvailable = function () {
            return ctrl.accaBuilderResults && ctrl.accaBuilderResults.length > 0;
        };

        ctrl.hasDataProcessed = function () {
            return ctrl.tips && ctrl.competitions;
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing some code it is tough to optimize.

You can try and eliminate any ng-show and ng-hide and use ng-if only. It will remove a lot of watchers if you have those present.

Additionally you can use the syntax below in your directives if you don’t need two-way binding. This will also remove a watcher. The more watchers you can remove in ng-repeat, the better.

```
{{:: expression  }}
```

Comment: Hi, I've added some code. Not sure if it will help though.

Comment: Yeah just go in those directives and look for hide/show and change to if. Going to add another optimization in my answer.

Comment: Could you give me an example if how to use hide/show and ng-if in the case above? Can't think that I can do that the way I'm using the ng-repeat and adding the results in the array

Comment: It looks like you are already using ng-if, but perhaps in the directive templates there might be some optimization you can do too